# Use ScrollBar in DropDownButton?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I want use a scrollbar like `ComboBox` in my `DropDown` button, the structure actually is this:

```
<Controls:DropDownButton Content="Nazioni" Width="120" Margin="0, 0, 20, 0" 
                         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}"
                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CombinedTemplate}"/>
```

but I don't see any `ScrollViewer` as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Comment: I've not used this component, but in many scroll aware components, you have to define a height property before scrolling will work.

Comment: @Alex So I guess that I need to style the ItemContainerTemplate with a default height and the scroll will appear?

Comment: Not necessarily. Unfortunately, there seems to be quite a lot of inconsistent behaviour in WPF where scrolling is concerned.

Comment: @Unchained In WPF, containers will tend to expand to the desired size of their children, unless you set a fixed size. That's a general truth, but the specifics of how to get in there and do that can change arbitrarily, because control templates can do arbitrary things.

Comment: @EdPlunkett you also have the issue that a component which includes a `ScrollViewer` doesn't necessarily expose it so you're not able to finely control the behaviour. WPF does some very frustrating things!

Comment: @Alex But we love it anyway! Sometimes.

Comment: @EdPlunkett or we switched to it when Microsoft said they were deprecating WinForms and by the time they withdrew the statement we'd written too much live code to go back and change it....

Comment: @Alex Honestly you couldn't pay me to go back to winforms. The stuff you can do with WPF more than compensates for the frustrations, for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125177/discussion-between-alex-and-ed-plunkett).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drop-down of the `DropDownButton` already contains a `ScrollViewer` (it is named `"SubMenuScrollViewer"`), so scrolling through its items is supported out-of-the-box. The thing is, that particular `ScrollViewer` is styled differently than a default `ScrollViewer` - assuming we're talking about vertical scrolling, it has two buttons above and below the list, responsible for scrolling up and down respectively, as shown below:

[image]

So your best bet is to make that particular `ScrollViewer` use the default style rather than a custom one. By inspecting the [*MahApps.Metro* source code](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.ContextMenu.xaml#L84) we can see that the `ScrollViewer` in question is wired to use a dynamic resource with a key value of `{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}`. So what you need to do is to supply a default style with that key for that control:

```
<Controls:DropDownButton (...)>
    <Controls:DropDownButton.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}"
               TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ScrollViewer}}" />
    </Controls.DropDownButton.Resources>
</Controls.DropDownButton>
```

This way the `ScrollViewer` within the drop-down will be styled with a default style shipped with *MahApps.Metro*.

Comment: Your answers is always the best. Thak you.

Answer (score 1):

To be certain that scrolling will behave as expected, you cannot rely on WPF to place a `ScrollViewer` where it should be.

As any content can be place on the dropdown, your best option is to drop a `ScrollViewer` straight onto the component.
This way, you can explicitly name it, and have access to its properties.
If you bind your list of countries to the `lstContent` box, you do away with all the messing.

```
   <extToolkit:DropDownButton Content="Click Me" Margin="15" >
        <extToolkit:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <ListBox Name="lstContent" ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CombinedTemplate}"/> 
            </ScrollViewer>
        </extToolkit:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
    </extToolkit:DropDownButton>
```