# Set a specific height for ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I want set a specific height for the DropDownButton ItemTemplate, in particular, I've a lot of elements inside the DropDown Button and actually the list displayed is too long as you can see in the image below, the structure is this:

```
<Controls:DropDownButton Content="Nazioni" Width="120" Margin="0, 0, 20, 0" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}"
                         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CombinedTemplate}"/>
```

[image]

Is possible set a specific height?

Comment: What happens if you try to set it `Height=100`

Comment: @AnjumSKhan only increase the height of the control not the itemtemplate

Comment: How ur `ItemTemplate` looks like ? Post that too plz.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan is already on the question.

Comment: I am talking about complete XAML for control and itemtemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the height of the element that is using the supplied `ItemTemplate` to display an item (this element is usually referred to as ***item container***), you should use the `ItemContainerStyle` property (inherited from `ItemsControl`):

```
<Controls:DropDownButton (...)>
    <Controls:DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="..." />
        </Style>
    </Controls.DropDownButton.ItemContainerStyle>
</Controls.DropDownButton>
```

### EDIT

If you want to limit the height of the drop-down itself the way to go about it is to use the `DropDownButton.MenuStyle` property:

```
<Controls:DropDownButton (...)>
    <Controls:DropDownButton.MenuStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContextMenu" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ContextMenu}}">
            <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="..." />
        </Style>
    </Controls.DropDownButton.MenuStyle>
</Controls.DropDownButton>
```

Comment: this is for the item, not for the container of the items. I need to set the height to the container

Comment: Thanks, working nice. Maybe you could check another question here, if you have free time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39902661/use-scrollbar-in-dropdownbutton thanks